# Angular-repeat display column IF equal to a value

Tags: sql, angularjs

I am using angularJS to display my result set into a table, that is filterable with totals etc. I was wondering if it would be possible to display a value based on another value if it is `=` to something. here is an example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in data">
     <td>{{c.type}}</td> //expects either 'fixed' or 'hourly'
     <td>{{c.fixed_rate}}</td>
     <td>{{c.hourly_rate}}</td>
</tr>
```

Therfore are you able to only display the fixed value if type is fixed, and hourly if the type is hourly without using any JQuery to hide elements?
My mind is kind of stumped on this as I am just a few months in with angular.

Data is pulled from a database* so if there is an SQL option I am all for it.

Comment: have you looked into `ng-if`?

Comment: @Claies I have not yet thanks for the suggestion! Going to look at the docs now, would I be able to inject this right into the repeat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in data | filter: filterHourlyOrFixed">
     <td>{{c.type}}</td> 
     <td ng-if="c.type == 'fixed'">{{c.fixed_rate}}</td>
     <td ng-if="c.type == 'hourly'">{{c.hourly_rate}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you want to filter by only those two values, add this function to your controller:

```
$scope.filterHourlyOrFixed = function (item) { 
    return item.type === 'fixed' || item.type === 'hourly'; 
};
```

If you do not want to filter by the value, remove `| filter: filterHourlyOrFixed` from the ng-repeat.

Also, when you have some time, do a little reading through the docs for [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow), [ngHide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide), and [ngFilter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). You'll probably be using these repeated.  Also, pay attention to the differences in how `ng-if`, `ng-show`, and `ng-hide` manipulate the DOM to achieve similiar results.

The differences are subtle, but important.

Comment: This is working perfectly, I did not know this was possible and will make future tasks MUCH easier. Thanks again, and to everyone else for the swift replies. Cheers

Comment: Excellent. Glad it helped. Take a look at the docs I just added to the answer when you have a chance.  There are a few different ways to achieve this with `ng-if`, `ng-switch`, `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-if` to remove or recreate parts of the DOM based on an expression.  for example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in data">
     <td>{{c.type}}</td> //expects either 'fixed' or 'hourly'
     <td ng-if="c.type=='fixed'">{{c.fixed_rate}}</td>
     <td ng-if="c.type=='hourly'">{{c.hourly_rate}}</td>
</tr>
```

You could also use a filter, if you are rendering identical DOM but want to exclude certain elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in data">
     <td ng-if="c.type =='fixed'">Fixed</td>
     <td ng-if="c.type =='hourly'">Hourly</td>
     <td ng-if="c.type =='fixed'">{{c.fixed_rate}}</td>
     <td ng-if="c.type =='hourly'">{{c.hourly_rate}}</td>
</tr>
```

Hope this helps!

http://embed.plnkr.co/Wes1Uf1OCCmKYa5wTP5s/preview